# Client Server exchanged message in order

Tags: java, client-server, serversocket

Below are my server and client authentication program. I was wondering am I doing it in the correct way, I want the message being send and receive in order which mean, the server only send the data after receiving the input from client, same thing goes to client, after receiving the response from server then replying.

```
Client class:

try {
        // Set up the socket
        connection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 55555);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        // Client --> Server 'A'
        BigInteger A = client.Step1(username, password);
        out.println(A);
        // Client received s , B
        byte[] s = new BigInteger(in.readLine()).toByteArray();
        BigInteger B = new BigInteger(in.readLine());
        // Client --> Server 'A'
        BigInteger M1 = client.Step2(new BigInteger(s), B);
        out.println(M1);
        // Client received M2
        BigInteger M2 = new BigInteger(in.readLine());

        boolean clientVerify = client.clientVerify(M2);
        if (clientVerify) {
            System.out.println("Client OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT OK");
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Server class:
try {
        socServer = new ServerSocket(55555);
        System.out.println("Waiting Client....");
        connection = socServer.accept();
        System.out.println("Client Connected");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

        // Server received A
        BigInteger A = new BigInteger(in.readLine());
        // Server --> Client 's' , 'B'
        out.println(new BigInteger(s));
        BigInteger B = server.step1(username, new BigInteger(s), v);
        out.println(B);
        server.step2(A);

        // Server received 'M1'
        BigInteger M1 = new BigInteger(in.readLine());
        boolean serverVerify = server.serverVerify(M1);
        if (serverVerify) {
            // Server --> Client 'M2'
            BigInteger M2 = server.step2(A, M1);
            out.println(M2);
            System.out.println("Server OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT OK");
            connection.close();
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Am I able to capture the data through Wireshark?